# Using jquery to change the value of the for attribute in a label tag

Tags: jquery, forms

Is it possible to change the value of the for attribute in a label tag with jquery?

e.g.

```
<label for="xxx">I am not changing</label>
to 
<label for="yyy">I am not changing</label>
```

I have been dynamically changing the name/id of the associated input but i cant work out how to change the label for value.

This is how i did the name/id change

```
$('#myinput_'+oldidnum).attr("name","myinput_"+newidnum);
$('#myinput_'+oldidnum).attr("id","myinput_"+newidnum);
```

thanks in advance 
:D

Comment: Did you even try assigning an ID to the `label` and then use `.attr('for','newvalue')`?

Comment: i didnt know how to specificy the correct label as they are all just <label> am i going to have to add an id?

Comment: Well, you have to identify them somehow. Adding an ID is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: i think a long day has prevent my brain from working....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See if your label is this: http://jsfiddle.net/QTM45/

```
<label for="xxx">I am not changing</label>
```

and if you want to change the `for` attribute value then use this:

```
$('label').attr('for','yyy');
```

if you assign an id to that label then

```
$('#labelID').attr('for','yyy');
```

Comment: How to get html value of that label without id?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh that actually depends on the structure but if you are interested in all the labels text then use `.text()` to get the text content of the label. As such in the answer like: `var labelText = $('label').text()` or you can use `.map()` to have an array of strings out of the labels text.